# Can a windows package be included in an installer?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, installation

I'm fairly new and inexperienced when it comes to creating installers and adding needed packages to them so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I have written a program in C# that uses the [STDFU library](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/540963/ST-Micro-electronics-Device-Firmware-Upgrade-DFU-D). I've created a setup project to create an installer for the application so it can be installed onto other Windows machines. The installer created works fine on my machine but did not work on one of my colleagues as they did not have Visual Studio installed and so they were receiving the error:

> Unable to load DLL 'STDFU.dll': The specified module could not be found.

I discovered that the problem for this error was because they didn't have the Visual C++ Redistributable package (vcredist_x86) installed. So my question is:

Is there a way in which I can get the package installed on each users machine as part of the installer for the application I'm creating or does each person have to install this package individually? And if I can add it as part of my installer how do I go about that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what type of installer are you using?

Comment: This is usually called a "pre-requisite" and many installers allow you to do this, how though depends on what installer you are using to generate your package.

Comment: I was just using the standard visual studio installer project.